# CSS Navigation Changing in Different Browsers

Tags: css, browser, navigation

I have an issue with my navigation - works great with this CSS in Safari & Firefox, but doesn't look right in Chrome or IE10.

Here is the site: `http://66.147.240.166/~peakeffe`

Here is the CSS driving the main navigation:

```
position: relative; 
z-index: 98; 
width: 900px; 
margin: 0 auto 0 575px; 
background: #4c2917; 
border-top: 0px solid #653600;
```

Comment: It's hanging off to the right in Firefox. Is that what "doesn't look right" means?

Comment: no, it looked fine for me in Firefox and Safari - it's hanging off the right in Chrome and WAAAAY off the right in IE10

Comment: Not sure what version of Firefox you're in, but it's broken for me. FF, Ch, and IE10 are all pretty standards-compliant and tend to render good CSS similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Your negative right margin is causing the menu to stick out. Try this:

```
.menuwrapper {
    right: 20px;
}
```

You seem to have a needlessly complex layout with all those negative margins. There's a small jog between your header and your content area, too. I'd look at simplifying things a bit.

Also try this:

```
.mainmenu.row {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: .mdivide { height: 30px; width: 0; border-left: 0px solid #444; margin: -30px auto 0 auto; } .mainmenu { position: relative; z-index: 98; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto 0 575px; background: #4c2917; border-top: 0px solid #653600; /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)l -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */ background: transparent;} .menuwrapper {float: right; width: 800px; /* right: -42%; */ position: relative; margin: -45px auto 0 auto; right: -90px;}

Comment: #mainmenu { background: url('') no-repeat left top; visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}

That's everything that guides it now. If I make a change to the menu wrapper, it's still off in some browsers. any way to specify different settings for different browsers?

Comment: Egads. Code doesn't belong in comments. You shouldn't need to do different CSS for different browsers in 2013. If you do it's probably due to a bad layout.

Comment: i agree - unfortunately i didn't design this site, I'm taking it over from someone else who flaked on the job. ;(

Comment: Ah. I feel your pain. Did you try my answer?

Comment: I did, but when I change the menuwrapper class, it screws up in Safari/Firefox instead of Chrome/IE. It's like I can have one or the other. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have [36 HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://66.147.240.166/~peakeffe&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [782 CSS errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://66.147.240.166/~peakeffe&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en). Get to work. However, many of those are vendor extensions or IE-only properties. Just don't know which ones but there are errors in there.